# How to make a chart in D3 work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataA=[10,20];
    d3.select("body").style("background-color", "green");

    var canvas = d3.select("body")
                   .append("svg")
                   .attr("width",500)
                   .attr("height",500);

    var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                     .data(dataA)
                     .enter()
                     .append("rect")
                     .attr("width",function (d){ return d*5;})
                     .attr("height",10)
                     .attr("y",function(d,i){ return i*20;});

</script>

</body>
```

This is the code I used for drawing a bar char in d3. how can I use node.js to do the same chart?

Comment: You want to render this chart server-side?  Use PhantomJS for that.

Comment: is it possible that way? or can i draw this chart only using node js?

Comment: You only need to render the data variable in a template with Node.js, then D3 library will do the rest. What's your Node.js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear enough, whether you want to just use node or node as a server and a client code. But still, you can go ahead with the two use cases given below.

1. **Server side scripting to generate a chart and take a snapshot:**
   I think yes, you can use node and [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and [node_phantomjs](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node)
2. **If you have both client and server side code:**
   You can render you web page using node and [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/)

You can keep your D3 code as it is. But, if you want to play with dynamic data being sent from the server, just have a look at full fledged [MEAN](http://meanjs.org/) framework.

Comment: thank you I render d3 code using ejs.it works for me.